# update vector field of pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, vector

I have a DataFrame with one column holding vector values:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6]}, index=["one", "two", "three"])
s = pd.Series([(i*10, i*11, i*12) for i in df["a"]], index=df.index)
df["vec"] = s
#df
```

but I cannot figure out, how to update these vector values. E.g:

```py
df.loc[df["a"]>1, "vec"] = np.array((1,2,3)) # doesn't work...
```

always getting something like

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Series on the right hand side:

```
m = df["a"]>1
df.loc[m, "vec"] = pd.Series([np.array((1,2,3))]*m.sum(),
                             index=df.index[m])
```

Output:

```
       a  b           vec
one    1  4  (10, 11, 12)
two    2  5     [1, 2, 3]
three  3  6     [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
new = tuple(np.array((1, 2, 3)))
m = df["a"] > 1
df.loc[m, "vec"] = df.loc[m, "vec"].map(lambda x: new)
```

---

Alternatively, using [`at`](https://pandas.DataFrame.at):

```
new = tuple(np.array((1, 2, 3)))

for idx in df[df["a"] > 1].index:
    df.at[idx, "vec"] = new
```

---

Output:

```
       a  b           vec
one    1  4  (10, 11, 12)
two    2  5     (1, 2, 3)
three  3  6     (1, 2, 3)
```